# How to scale down 3D model in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, blender

I was able to make a simple RC Car AR app using ARKit and SceneKit Vehicle physics. But now I need to change the car model. I'm using the [SceneKit vehicle demo car model](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html)

I was able to import it into my project as shown

**Here -**

[image: here] .

But when I place the car object on the plane it is too large. How can I scale down the model. When I import the model into blender as dae file it has no textures and it is not visible

**As shown here -**

[image: as shown here]

Comment: What I noticed some time ago, in the demo-car project from apple, the wheels of the car are organized in so called locater nodes. I downloaded your project from your other question, and the wheels are direct nodes. I might be a good try to rebuild the same structures to your desired car model, as it is in the demo project from apple. also apply the scale and rotation transforms to each node to the effective size you are looking for. Setting up a functional car can be quiet tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If your model loses textures when imported into Blender, it's likely due to a compatibility issue or how the model is exported from the original source. You might need to ensure that the textures are properly UV-mapped and assigned in Blender before exporting the model.